# Loading / creating views from NIB for GeoLocation - IOS and MapKit

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, geolocation, mapkit

I have two classes - MapView and MapController. The main idea is to make View a shared object in MVC pattern.

1. MapView has IBOutlet "mapView" for MKMapView located in MapNib.xib
2. MapController contains property "mapView" referencing to class MapView

Then i try to set some properties of MKMapView from controller and it does not react on this anyway. For example i try in MapController :

```
self.mapView.mapView.showUserLocation = YES; // does not show blue point ...
```

MapView Class :

```
@interface MapView : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

...

//UINib *view = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MapView" bundle:nil];
//[view instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

@end
```

MapController Class :

```
@interface MapController : UIViewController<
    CLLocationManagerDelegate, 
    MKMapViewDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, retain) MapModel *mapModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MapView *mapView;

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView = [[[MapView alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.mapView.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;

} @end
```

I tried to make MapView a subclass of UIView, UINib, UIViewcontroller, tried to load NIB directly using UINib::nibWithNibName, UIViewController::initWithNibName, UIViewController::loadNibNamed - it does not matter ... **i can see the map but blue point is not shown anyway** ... why???
Only one combination works for me - to name NIB the same way as controller (MapController.xib) and add outlet for MKMapView as controller property ... **it seems like it is impossible to load NIB / View in one class and use it in another, am i right?**

Somehow this works fine :

```
@interface MapController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;  // NIB was renamed to MapController.xib

...

@end
```

And then in controller :

```
self.mapView.showUserLocation = YES; // now this shows blue dot ... why???
```

Thanks, Art

Answer (score 1):

IBOutlets do not need to be created. The NIB creates them and assigns them to your vars, your are overwriting it by allocing and initing a new mapview and saving it to that variable

Comment: It makes sense ... though i do not understand where exactly i init an IBOutlet? I am allocing only my custom class called "MapView" and it has IBOutlet which i do NOT touch ... or am i wrong? Do you mean that if i init my class this causes to alloc memory for its IBOutlet too?